# How do I make Visual Studio put -lrt after the name of my source file when it calls gcc?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, linker

I'm trying to make Visual Studio 2022 call GCC to compile a C program that depends on librt. For this to work, `-lrt` needs to be on the command line, *after* the name of the file that needs it, like this: `gcc -g -Wall -o mqtest mqtest.c -lrt`

The problem is that when I add `-lrt` to "Additional Options" under "Command Line" in Visual Studio, it passes it *before* the name of the file that needs it, which results in an undefined reference error.

[image: Property Page]